# Launch non-immersive applications without switching to desktop mode

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

In windows 8 when you launch a non-immersive application (i.e. a desktop application) from the start menu or by pressing a short-cuts from the menu, windows switches from the start menu to desktop mode. Is there a way i.e. manifest or com contracts to prevent this from happening?

The reason I am asking is because I am trying to create a small application to take partial screenshots i.e. similiar in functionallity to "snipping tool" or "(send to) one note". However because of the transition, it is capturing the content of the screen during the transition.

Comment: What happens if you create an app with no window?

Comment: Same behaviour, it switches from the start menu to the desktop.